# What happened to the shipwrecked guy after Delfino Plaza is flooded?

Tags: super-mario-sunshine

He doesn't seem to be present during or after the flooding. Can you find him somewhere else in Delfino Plaza? Seems a bit sinister for a Mario game...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the flooding subsides, you can find him on the shore of Delfino Plaza across from the island - Ironically, his speech bubble says something on the lines of "I wish I could get back there..."